# Making an empty box next to text

Tags: minipage, fbox

I'm trying to recreate a document template thats in a PDF, in one portion of it, I need to create a box with a word of text next to it, like so:[image: Original]

I've tried using functions like `\fbox` and `\framebox`, however the text on the left of it, which should be aligned at the top, ends up in the middle or the bottom. Like in this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\begin{document}
Коментар:
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}
    {0.7\linewidth}\hfill\vspace{5cm}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Use `\begin{minipage}[t]`

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `\framebox`. Just in case you'd like the box to go automatically to the right margin, it's easy to do with the `linegoal` package, which measures the distance from its point of insertion to the right margin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\begin{document}

Коментар:
\framebox[\linegoal][l]{\rule[-5cm]{0pt}{\dimexpr5cm+1ex}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use `[t]` for the `minipage`. It's easier with `\parbox`, though. The setting to `\fboxsep` will make the box the exact specified dimensions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\newcommand{\blankbox}[2]{% #1 = width, #2 = total height
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][#2]{#1}{\strut}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Коментар: \blankbox{0.7\linewidth}{5cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add option `[t]` (top) to the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\begin{document}
Коментар:
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t]
    {0.7\linewidth}\hfill\vspace{5cm}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]